# Showing error in this conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two cells and if the value is greater then format the entire row in red and if it is lesser then yellow and if the values are equal then green. Am getting error in the if loop and the data is dynamic so no specific range value

I get this error:

> runtime error 1004 method range of object_global failed

on the first line of this code. Why?

```
If Range("c" & i2).Value > Range("D" & i2).Value Then ' <~~~~ Error
    Range("E" & i2) = "Resource Not fully Utilised"
    Range("a" & i2, "e" & i2).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
ElseIf Range("c" & i2).Value < Range("D" & i2).Value Then
    Range("E" & i2) = "Resource over Utilised"
    Range("a" & i2, "e" & i2).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Range("E" & i2) = "Resource properlly Utilised"
    Range("a" & i2, "e" & i2).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

Comment: If Range("c" & i2) > Range("D" & i2) Then

Comment: am checking whether the value in each cell is equal or greater or lesser and based on it am updating the formatting

Comment: Please put question clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link. Please make clear **what** error you get, and on what line.

Comment: If you want quick help, then write a clear question. What's the value of `i2`?

Comment: the value of i2 changes after every loop. Like now it is 1 so it refers to "c1" after that it increments to 2 so "C2". I dont know if this is the right way to use it but am giving it a shot

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of `i2` *when the error occurs*?? Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)).

Comment: The value in i2 is 1

Comment: I predefied it to be as  'i2=1'

Comment: You will have to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, else we can't help. See this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help. But there is another problem. How do i make it increment after each check

Comment: This is turning out to be too much work. I'm giving up, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a for loop to solve my problem:

```
row1 = Range("c1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
row1 = row - 1
For i2 = 1 To row1
    If Range("c" & i2).Value > Range("D" & i2).Value Then
        Range("E" & i2) = "Resource Not fully Utilised"
        Range("a" & i2, "e" & i2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ElseIf Range("c" & i2).Value < Range("D" & i2).Value Then
        Range("E" & i2) = "Resource over Utilised"
        Range("a" & i2, "e" & i2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        Range("E" & i2) = "Resource Fully Utilised Properly"
        Range("a" & i2, "e" & i2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
Next i2
```